# MySQL updating all of the data

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with my MySQL code to get one table to update another.

I have created a test table before carrying out the code on a live table, but as the information was updated last week I am looking to update this on my test table also.

```
tab_id_master - Live table
tab_id_master_test - Test table
```

ID - is also my Primary Key

I have tried the code displayed below but I cant get the table to update, any help would be appreciated.

```
UPDATE it_asset_register.tab_id_master_test
SET current_category = (SELECT ID
FROM it_asset_register.tab_id_master
WHERE tab_id_master_test.ID = tab_id_master.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID
FROM it_asset_register.tab_id_master
WHERE tab_id_master_test.ID = tab_id_master.ID);`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want set  it_asset_register.tab_id_master_test.current_category 
with the value from it_asset_register.tab_id_master.current_category for each corresponding  ID you could use an inner join

```
UPDATE it_asset_register.tab_id_master_test  a 
INNER JOIN it_asset_register.tab_id_master  b  ON a.ID =b.id  
SET  a.current_category = b.current_category
```

Comment: thank you very much for getting back to me, I keep getting an 1054 error message with this code